# Spring data mongo use OR in Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Let´s see if somebody can help with this.

I want use Repository of Spring Data mongodb, and I want use Query annotation to filter the find by value `A=10 or A=20`

```
  @Query("{A: 10, A:20}")
  findById(int id);
```

Obiously "," try to make an AND, and I need an OR.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think this might work

```
@Query("{'$or':[ {'A':10}, {'B':20} ] }")
```

Comment: @FakeUser @Query("{$or : [{'type':?0},{'key':?1},{'username':?2}]}") is this the right query ?

Comment: @mahendrakawde the query is correct for searching by `type` or `key` or `username`

Comment: If this answer does not work try this:  `@Query("{'\$or':[ {'A':10}, {'B':20} ] }")`

Answer (score 103):

Or if you are using a Criteria API

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("A").is(10),Criteria.where("B").is(20));
Query query = new Query(criteria);

mongoOps.find(query, <Yourclass>.class, "collectionName");
```

Comment: gives error that 'The method find(Query, Class<UserMetaData>, String) is undefined for the type UserRepo' ?

Answer (score 15):

You can use Spring Data MongoDB like this:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(
    Criteria.where("").orOperator(
        Criteria.where("A").is(10),
        Criteria.where("B").is(20)
    )
);

mongoTemplate.find(query, YourClazz.class, "CollectionName");
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to helloJava answer, If you already have query with other criteria's you can add orOperation directly on query.addCriteria as below.

```
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("fieldA").is(value),
                Criteria.where("fieldB").is(value2)));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the $in operator in Spring Java:

`Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("field").in(listOfOptions);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) operator for that.  I don't know Java Spring, but given your example, the `Query` part should look like:

```
@Query("{A: {$in: [10, 20]}}")
```

Comment: Thanks but that annotation structure does not work in Spring data repository, somebody else has another idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring's BasicQuery:

```
DBObject queryCondition = new BasicDBObject();        
BasicDBList values = new BasicDBList();
values.add(new BasicDBObject("A", 10));
values.add(new BasicDBObject("B", 20));
queryCondition.put("$or", values);
Query query = new BasicQuery(queryCondition);
mongoTemplate.find(query, clazz);
```

Comment: note everyone, this construct, besides having less objects created, is also handy if you want to exclude NULL conditions from an OR operator.

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'BasicQuery(com.mongodb.DBObject)'

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = new Query();  
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();  
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("category").is("your_Value_Category"), 
    Criteria.where("parentCategory").is("your_Value_ParentCategory"));
query.addCriteria(criteria);
mongoTemplate.find(query, YourPersistenceClass.class);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Spring's Query structure:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(10).orOperator(Criteria.where("id").is(20));
this.client.findOne(query, clazz);
```

Comment: It wont work because using above, an id is already fixed and in that base clause the or will be applied. But OP wants to have a direct first level Or clause.

Comment: Can we apply orOperator with few more conditions ?